# Solana cli cannot be installed normally, the connection to the network timed out during installation

Tags: solana-program, wallet, cli

Solana cli cannot be installed normally, the connection to the network timed out during installation,Is it true that the service in China is not supported?And my code is wrong, saying I didn't enter it.`{ "compilerOptions": { "outDir": "./build-ts", "declaration": true, "allowUnreachableCode": false, "noImplicitAny": true, "target": "es2017", "moduleResolution": "node", "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, "allowJs": true }, "include": [ "./src/**/*" ] }`

[image]
[image]